# Unit test for asyn function inside sails controller where async function called independently

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sails.js, sinon

I have one sails controller where I am doing something like :

```
...
function asynFunc(){
/* some logic */

} 
module.exports = {
    myFunc: function () {

     // Call async function and return
     asynFunc();
     return true;
    }
};
```

Now I wanted to write unit test for asynFunc. I am able to write unit test of myFunc but not  asynFunc (get data, validate data).

Please let me know :

1. How can i mock asyncFunc
2. How can i unit test asynFunc

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to test private function? If you have it private, seems you may test it when you test other methods?

If you really need to test it, you can do the following:
myModule.js

```js
async function asyncFunc(){
  /* some logic */
} 
module.exports = {
  myFunc: async function () {
    // Call async function and return
    await asyncFunc();
    return true;
  }
};
```

test.js

```js
const rewire = require('rewire');
const myModule = rewire('./myModule');

describe('unit/myModule:', () => {
  const revert = (obj) => {
    obj.__revert__();
    delete obj.__revert__;
  };

  it('asyncFunc', async () => {
    const asyncFuncSpy = jasmine.createSpy();
    asyncFuncSpy.__revert__ = myModule.__set__('asyncFunc', asyncFuncSpy);

    const actual = await myModule.myFunc();

    expect(actual).toBeThruthy();
    expect(asyncFuncSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    revert(asyncFuncSpy)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a Bad use of a controller in 99% of the cases! Wrap that function into a Service and unity test the Service.

```
// Controller
module.exports = {
     myFunc: function () {

     // Call async function and return
     MyService.asynFunc();
     return true;
     }
};

// Service
module.exports = {
     async : function asynFunc(){
     /* some logic */

    }
}
```